# inverse of function $xe^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, exponential-function, special-functions

Let W the Lambert function that is the inverse function of $xe^x$.Is true that if $c > 1$, then $w(cx)\leq cw(x)$ for $x\geq 0$?

Can I apply the property $ln(x)-ln(ln(x))\leq W$ for $x\geq e$?

Comment: since $xe^x$ is increasing and convex, its inverse is cancave, then apply jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**. We want to prove that for any $x\geq 0$ and $c>1$ we have
$$ W(cx)\leq c\cdot W(x)$$
where $W$ is Lambert's function.

**Step 2**. $xe^x$ is an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. It follows that if $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers, proving $a\leq b$ **is equivalent** to proving $a e^a\leq b e^b$. We apply this principle to the above inequality, turning it into

$$ W(cx) e^{W(cx)} \leq c W(x) e^{c W(x)}. $$

**Step 3**. By the very definition of $W$, the LHS of the last inequality equals $cx$, while the RHS equals $cW(x) e^{W(x)} e^{(c-1)W(x)}$. Thus the last inequality **is equivalent** to

$$ cx \leq cx e^{(c-1)W(x)} $$
or to
$$ 1 \leq e^{(c-1)W(x)} $$
which is trivial.

Comment: why $w(cx) e^{w(cx)}\leq c w(x) e^{c w(x)}$ implies $w(cx)\leq cw(x)$? how you use that if $f(x)=xe^x$ and $a\leq b$ then $f(x)=ae^a\leq f(b)=be^b$?

Comment: I understand that you use the consequent, not?

Comment: yes Aurizio is wrong, took $a=w(cx)$ and $b=cw(x)$ and applies the conclusion.

Comment: I am not wrong, I am going to rephrase the whole thing.

Comment: @mathd: can you follow my proof now?